# DB2 how to grant SYSADM

Tags: ubuntu, db2

The SQL command

```
GRANT SYSADM TO db2inst1;
```

fails with the following message:

```
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-707, SQLSTATE=42939, SQLERRMC=SYSADM, DRIVER=4.19.49
SQLState:  42939
ErrorCode: -707
```

The installation is a fresh DB2 installation on Ubuntu 14.04.

I had to do manual install since the installer did not work.

Therefore I executed all the manual installation steps. Which resulted in having three user: `db2inst1`, `dasusr1`, `db2fenc1`.

And I would like the add the privilege to `db2inst1`.
I tried to grant the privilege with each of the above mentioned users.

**EDIT:**

After some research I use

```
get dbm cfg
```

to print the current configuration which prints out this line (among many others)

```
SYSADM group name                        (SYSADM_GROUP) = DB2IADM1
```

Does it use the linux user groups?

```
groups db2inst1
db2inst1 : db2iadm1 dasadm1
```

**So how can I add a user to this group? Or is db2inst1 already SYSADM?? How can I verify??**

In the IBM Data Studio it seems that the user does not have this role!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it this way.

Those who you want to have SYSADM authorities must be the members of the group that is specified with

**update dbm cfg using SYSADM_GROUP thegroup;**

(... but this question will surely be moved.)

Comment: OK thanks for the information. Is teh group an operating system group? Please specify so that I can accept the answer.

Comment: Yes. Usually, when the instance creation is part of the install procedure it's  db2iadm1 and created as well, can be found in /etc/group.